# How to place add to cart,quantity and attributes next to each other

Tags: theming, blocks, ubercart

The default position of the add to cart, quantity and attributes list is in a block.

Is there any way to have them next to each other horizontally. I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: This sounds like a CSS question, where you would `float` or `inline-block` these pieces of information next to each other. If this isn't the correct interpretation, please clarify your question with more details.

Comment: are you doing this in a view? This is a common ubercart request and you might just need to set the uc_catalog fields view to inline display.